# Sampling 1000 lines from a bunch of gzipped files with PIG

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hdfs

I'm very new to Pig so I may be going about this the wrong way. I have a bunch of gzipped files in a directory in Hadoop. I'm trying to sample around 1000 lines from all of these files put together. It doesn't have to be exact, so I wanted to use `SAMPLE`. `SAMPLE` needs a probability of sampling a line, rather than the number of lines that I need, so I thought I should count up the number of lines among all these files and than simply divide 1000 by that count and use it as the probability. This will work, since I don't need to have exactly 100 lines at the end. Here is what I got so far:

```
raw = LOAD '/data_dir';
cnt = FOREACH (GROUP raw ALL) GENERATE COUNT_STAR(raw);
cntdiv = FOREACH cnt GENERATE (float)100/ct.$0;
```

Now I'm not sure how to use the value in `cntdiv` in `SAMPLE`. I tried `SAMPLE raw cntdiv` and `SAMPLE raw cntdiv.$0`, but they don't work. Can I even use that value in the call to `SAMPLE`? Maybe there is a much better way of accomplishing what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the description in the ticket originally requesting this feature: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-1926

I haven't tested this, but it looks like this should work:

```
raw = LOAD '/data_dir';
samplerate = FOREACH (GROUP raw ALL) GENERATE 1000.0/COUNT_STAR(raw) AS rate;
thousand = SAMPLE raw samplerate.rate;
```

The important thing is to refer to your scalar by name (`rate`), not by position (`$0`).

Comment: Turns out I was dealing with a really old version of Pig that did not have this feature. I ended up saving line numbers in a file and after that running a second job that gathered the sample. This would work on a newer version though.

Comment: If you need to roll your own version of this since your Pig is old, you can always `JOIN` the single number in to all lines `USING 'replicated'`, then `FILTER` by whether a random number is less than your threshold. Might save you some time/extra files.